# Batch starts to run in Windows Scheduler, but does not execute all lines

Tags: windows, batch-file, task, scheduler

I have a very simple batch that backs up a set of folders.  I run the batch manually without any issue, but when I schedule it to run it start to run fine but never completes.  It creates the appropraite dated folder and stops before it ever copies any folders/files.

Here is the code from the .bat

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime ^| find "."') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"

set datestamp=%MM%-%DD%-%YYYY%
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"

md F:\MyArchives\%datestamp%
xcopy U:\Kristi\Project\*.* F:\MyArchives\%datestamp%\ /f/s
```

I have it set to run as my user name whether I am logged on or not.  I have it set to run the highest privileges.  It is sched for 1:45 am every day.  I have checked Wake the computer to run this task.  I am running Windows 7 Enterprise

When I look at the history in Scheduler, it states the following:

- Task Triggered on Scheduler
- Task Engine received message to start task
- Tast Started
- Action started
- Created Task Process
- Action completed
- Task completed

I am at a loss.  I have searched this site extensively and I have also googled it until I am blue in the face.

I have also exported the Task xml file and it is listed below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2014-11-04T10:50:29.1301378</Date>
    <Author>AMERICAS\jfges</Author>
    <Description>Backs up the Projects folder to the Passport Drive every night.  This will create a dated folder that will need to be deleted eventually for space.  Batch is to run every night</Description>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2014-11-04T01:45:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>AMERICAS\jfges</UserId>
      <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>false</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>false</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT8H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
    <RestartOnFailure>
      <Interval>PT10M</Interval>
      <Count>3</Count>
    </RestartOnFailure>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Users\jfges\Desktop\backup.bat</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

I have tried to provide you guys with everything that I have seen anyone ask for on similar questions that I have read on here.  I REALLY hope that someone is able to help me with this.

The only other thing that I can think to tell you is that I am trying to back up approx 17G of data each night.  I wouldn't think that would matter since it is not even starting to copy the data over, but I thought I would mention it.

Any help would be greatly apprectiated!

Comment: Are either U: or F: mapped network drives? If so, they need to be explicitly defined inside the batch script.

Comment: U is a mapped network drive.  Would I do this by referring to it as \\drivename\Kristi\Projects ?

Comment: @SomethingDark that took care of the issue!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be some reasons this doesn't work.
1. try to run the batch from cmd to see if it works (I assume you did that already)
2. xcopy to/from netword drive [need mapping/privileges set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578175/xcopy-with-credentials-on-remote-machine) - so do that
3. try adding "" around folders/path data as this might help, even with short names (even if having no space in their names)
4. you might need to use [runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx) if no user is logged on (unsure in case of xcopy but if I remember right you'll need this)
5. Last but not least, check Event Viewer `eventvwr.msc` for the error. Hopefully you'll find indication of what went wrong. If not, [make the task visible](https://superuser.com/questions/656964/what-user-must-a-scheduled-task-run-as-in-order-to-be-visible-for-all-users) and try to repeat

If still struggling, ["schedule the batch"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614766/run-a-script-on-windows-startup-without-a-user-logged-on) to run when Windows starts (to see if Task Manager messes up something)
If all fails, please update the question accordingly (i.e. with the new data/information you collected).